# Swift: How do I add a name to the UITextView in a UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

So I have a `UITextView` in a `UIAlertController` and later in the code I am writing the following:

```
        for(var i: Int = 0; i < self.codesdemo.count; i++) {
        if let code = self.textField.text {
            if code == codesdemo[i] {
                // This should present view controller if codes is real/worked
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
                let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Demo") as UIViewController
                self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    }))}
```

Basically saying that if someone writes [i] in the textView it goes to another viewcontroller. 
Here is my full code that relates:

```
@IBAction func EnterCode(sender: AnyObject) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Code", message: "Enter a code to access your chatroom", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField:UITextField) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Code"
    }

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Enter", style: .Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        let textField = alert.textFields!.first!






    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    //  Loops through the codes array
    for(var i: Int = 0; i < self.codesdemo.count; i++) {
        if let code = self.textField.text {
            if code == codesdemo[i] {
                // This should present view controller if codes is real/worked
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
                let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Demo") as UIViewController
                self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    }))}
```

In this section:  if let code = self.textField.text {
I get an error that says: **Value type `Homeviewcontroller` (which is the viewcontroller)has no member of `textField`.** I don't understand because I thought when I created the textField in the `UIAlertController` it is called `textField` I am wondering if there is something I need to do to rename it so I am able to fix this error. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to present UIAlertController within action handler block.. that's reason your alertview will not appear in view:
I have edited some line of code of button action method ..here is code

```
@IBAction func EnterCode(sender: AnyObject) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Code", message: "Enter a code to access your chatroom", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler{ (textField:UITextField!) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Code"
        } 

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Enter", style: .Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            let textField: UITextField = alert.textFields!.first! as UITextField

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

            for(var i: Int = 0; i < self.codesdemo.count; i++) {
                if let code: String = textField.text {
                    if code == codesdemo[i] {
                        // This should present view controller if codes is real/worked
                        //other code here 
                    }
                }
            }

        }))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```